# Como agregar filas mediante codigo a un DataGridView que se llena con una consulta a una BD

Tags: c#, sql

He leido varios casos abiertos de este tipo pero realmente no veo uno que se adecue a mi caso. Bien les planteo mi caso;

Tengo un DataGridview el cual mediante consulta a la BD lo lleno y quiero agregarle filas mediante TextBox que se encuentran en el mismo formulario.

Mi codigo para agregarle filas es:

```
string[] fila = new string[] { txtidproducto.Text, txtproducto.Text,txtmarca.Text,txtdescripcion.Text,txtcantidad.Text,txtprecio.Text};

                                dtgv.Rows.Add(fila);
```

Si ejecuto ese codigo me da error de que "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.' Los casos que he visto de este es que el usuario trata de agregarle filas al DataGridView que ya tenia filas agregadas mediante consulta, entonces quiere agregarle otras filas mediante otra consulta y lo realizan mediante array (realmente el tema de arrays no lo manejo muy bien) y ademas al no querer hacer una segunda consulta sino una insercion directa creo que esos casos no se adecuan al mio. Por favor ayuda.

asi lleno el DataGridView:

```
string sql2 = @"SELECT DISTINCT cabeza.Id_producto,detalle.Producto,detalle.Marca,detalle.Descripcion,cabeza.Cantidad, cabeza.Precio FROM Tab_entrada_mercancia_detalle AS cabeza INNER JOIN Tab_productos AS detalle ON cabeza.Id_producto = detalle.Id_producto where cabeza.Id_entrada=@numeroentrada";

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, cn);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numeroentrada", txtSalidaEntrada.Text);


                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dtgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas mostrando informacion proveniente de una base de datos no puedes usar el `Rows.Add()` tienes que agregar los nuevos datos al datatable

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Id_producto"] = txtidproducto.Text;
row["Producto"] = txtproducto.Text;
//resto de las columnas
dt.Rows.Add(row);

dtgv.DataSource = dt;
```

como veras el dato se agrega al datatable y luego lo asignas al datagridview

Si necesitas agregar una row en algun evento puede obtener el datatable usando

```
DataTable dt = dtgv.DataSource as DataTable;
```

agregas la row y vuelves asignar al grid

Comment: Hola, Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda pero una pregunta ese codigo agregara esa nueva fila al final del DataGridView o al principio(Si la agrega al principio podrias decirme como agregarla al final?) te pregunto ya que no puedo probar el codigo ahora por que no tengo acceso al proyecto.

Comment: lo agrega al final, para agregarlo al principio se usa el dt.Rows.Insert(row, 0); indicando la primer posicion